# Database monitoring Scripts Automation

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, db2, build-automation

I am working in the configuration part of the application, so i am new to this data base side configuration.

Database Oracle,SQL,DB2

I need some clarifications on below Questions:

1. How to monitor the database changes.
2. How to Track the changes in the database with any specific tool or script
3. How to roll back the database if to any specific point of change (like we are doing in source control management).
4. How compare last two changes in UI or with help any other tools.

Comment: What sort of work have you already done on this?

Comment: See if this thread helps: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-a-group-track-database-schema-changes

Comment: Guys i am working in package and deployment team, here we are backage the all the DB scripts and deploye to the distination server,but some time wrong unwanted changes are made by development team, for that, i need to rollback the changes back to old state, for all three data base i mentioned in the description.

Comment: Is there any possible to revert the database changes via Python database script, any scripting tool to automate this process

Answer (score 0):

You should check [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/). Of course you can track changes made by Data Studio itself. If you issue a DDL statement outside of the Data Studio, Data studio will not be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for your responce , pls mention any open source tool is availble for this activity

Comment: May I ask you why you want an open source one? 
IBM Data Studio is not open source but it if FREE to use.

Comment: Really i dont have any idea about that ,thats thank anyway, i will check on this

Comment: Could you confirm i can use this tool to monitre , SQL,Oracle, or it only use for DB2 database server only

Comment: You can connect to DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, MySql,Sybase, HSQLDB, Derby and MaxDB with IBM Data Studio.

Comment: Any other open source tool is available m to perform this operation

Comment: Is there any possible to revert the database changes via Python database script, any scripting tool to automate this process